# Single sign on using facebook/google/ms etc on a multi tenant SAAS software

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization, single-sign-on

We have a SAAS software where each Tenant has its own set of users with multiple roles like manager, user, contractor etc with different privileges.
Today we have all these in our own database and have our own login. So for every tenant we create an account entity and each user has a foreign key to the account entity. Users also have roles which we use for authorization.
Thus when a user logs in we create a JWT token with account id and the roles.

We want to add feature to support logins using google, facebook, microsoft etc along with our  existing one. Thus when a tenant is created a list of users can be added say, abcd@gmail.com, xyz@fcebook.com, etc.

When a user choses to login to our app using say google we will redirect to google and get it authenticated and get the token in return. However this token has roles to access google resources. We can map the users to the tenant based on the pre-created list of users as mentioned earlier.

We now want that the client gets a JWT token with our roles so that when the client calls our APIs from different micro services it can access our resources with proper authorization.

I need help in how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but for now I am doing the following way. For e.g. microsoft

1. Do login via microsoft using msal libarary.
2. Get the access token silently
3. pass the access token to our user management service.
   a. user management validates if the login exists using email.
   b. It uses the access token to call a microsoft graph api.
   c. if successfull it generates its own access token and returns to the UI
4. UI stores both the tokens and uses our token to access our apis.
5. On logout it deletes both the tokens.